# Get requested service in Restler iAuthenticate implementation

Tags: php, regex, url, restler

I'm using Restler to develop a REST api and I need to get the requested service from the iAuthenticate implementation.

So far I have managed to get here:

```
$m = preg_match('/.+?\/(?P<api>.+?)\/(?P<service>\w+)/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` has this form: `/somedir/apiclass/requestedservice?...`

I've tried my regex here: http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php with my actual uri
and it works perfectly. When I try to parse the request url inside my iAuthenticate implementation it just don't work.

Does anybody know how to enable regex within restler iAuthenticate implementation? How can I display errors in Restler instead of a blank page?

Thanks!

[EDIT]

I wasn't passing the variable to store the match object,  `preg_match` recieves a third argument to store it and just returns a boolean. Case closed.

Comment: What is the purpose? there may be better ways to achieve what you want. Restler already finds the api class and api method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it like this:

```
preg_match('/.+?\/(?P<api>.+?)\/(?P<service>\w+)/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $mo);

$api = $mo['api'];
$service = $mo['service'];
```